# Showing $e^{(α Ω)} e^{(β Ω)} = e^{((α + β) Ω)}$ with Wolfram Technology

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

**Context.** I am currently reading a Quantum Mechanics book in which it is stated that it is "obvious" (without proof) that

$$
e^{(α Ω)} e^{(β Ω)} = e^{((α + β) Ω)}
$$

where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\Omega$ is a square matrix of complex scalars, and $e^{\Omega}$ is defined as

$$
e^\Omega = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\Omega^n}{n!}
$$

whenever $\lim_{n \to \infty} \Omega^n$ converges.

**Question:** Is there a way to induce Wolfram technologies to induce a **step-by-step proof** (or proof-aid) of this identity?

**Attempt:** I have tried typing

```
Prove E^(\alpha*\Omega)*E^(\beta*\Omega)== E^((\alpha + \beta)*\Omega)
```

into Wolfram Alpha, where all I get is the unhelpful

> [image]

To make things worse, here I assume WolframAlpha has no idea $\Omega$ is meant to be a square matrix instead of a normal scalar.

Comment: `MatrixExp[]` is the appropriate function here and not `Exp[]`.

Comment: Is [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Prove+MatrixExp%5B%28%5Calpha*%5COmega%29%5D*MatrixExp%5B%28%5Cbeta*%5COmega%29%5D%3D%3D+MatrixExp%5B%28%28%5Calpha+%2B+%5Cbeta%29*%5COmega%29%5D) what you mean?

Comment: This proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/863591/547370 for the regular exponential will work for you since `X` commutes with itself

Comment: Obviously that is not using Mathematica, but proving series properties for general cases like this is something I've always found Mathematica struggles with

Comment: b3m2a: The connection isn't obvious to me (though it definitely feels like it should be related), but this isn't really pertinent to Mathematica.SE.  I'm mainly trying to figure out how to the Wolfram tool to help me with problems like this.

Comment: @George without commutativity you can't write line 2 in that proof. With commutativity everything works. Now say `a = \alpha  \Omega` & `b = \beta \Omega` and everything will fall out as usual but now with matmuls instead of multiplications. As far as Mathematica will help you...I'm not sure. You might be able to have Mathematica build a series of expressions for you and then take some limits? I don't even know if Mathematica can do it, tbh

Comment: It is funny, you try to get the proof, but any system is going to guess that alpha and beta are complex numbers and Omega is a matrix? No full information in, not result out. Moreover, this is not a mathematica question.